# URL change in SpecsFor.Mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, integration-testing

Say that you configure your `SpecsForIntegrationHost` like this.

```
config.UseApplicationAtUrl("http://mylocaldomain.com");
```

Some of your pages are located on subdomains, because you configured it that way in your RouteConfig. You cannot test these, because you need to change the host.

```
public class When_Viewing_Global_Page : SpecsFor<MvcWebApp>
{
    protected override void When()
    {
        //The HomeController.Global is triggered only
        //in the URL http://global.mylocaldomain.com
        //this results in 404
        SUT.NavigateTo<HomeController>(c => c.Global());
    }

    [Test]
    public void Then_It_Shows_The_Project_Name()
    {
        string text = SUT.AllText();
        SUT.AllText().ShouldContain("This is the Global Page");
        //This will fail because the page contains "Not Found"
    }
}
```

Is there a way to tell your test in SpecsFor.Mvc to change the base URL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out there is a public static property which holds the base url name. You can simply change it but you have to change it back if your tests are unsorted.

```
public class When_Viewing_Global_Page : SpecsFor<MvcWebApp>
{
    protected override void When()
    {
        //change to base url to the subdomain
        MvcWebApp.BaseUrl = "http://global.mylocaldomain.com";
        SUT.NavigateTo<HomeController>(c => c.Global());
    }

    [Test]
    public void Then_It_Shows_The_Project_Name()
    {
        string text = SUT.AllText();
        SUT.AllText().ShouldContain("This is the Global Page");
        //Success
    }

    [TestFixtureTearDown]
    public void Cleanup()
    {
        //you have to change that back to the URL that was
        //set up in your SpecsForIntegrationHost
        MvcWebApp.BaseUrl = "http://mylocaldomain.com";
    }
}
```

This should be easily abstracted in a parent class though.

Comment: That's a good solution. I'd be interested in trying to find a way to add support for this scenario conventionally though.  Are the controllers that target a subdomain distinguishable in some way?  Are they in a separate namespace or something like that?

Comment: First, let me tell you that SpecsFor.Mvc is ABSOLUTELY FANTASTIC :) Second: no, not in controllers ... The URLs are hardcoded in the applicationhost.config bindings and in the RouteConfig with constraints that can detect the host by Regex ( first route constraint is ^mydomain\.com$  ... second route constraint is ^global\.mydomain\.com$  ... they both redirect to the same controller but different actions)